# A small question about off-diagonal long ranged order

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I am studying the off-diagonal long ranged order from the book *Superconductivity, Superfluids, and Condensates* by James F. Annett. Thereof, I got stuck in a small step from (5.63) to (5.64)(Section 5.5):

\begin{align}
\rho_1(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')&=\langle\psi^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\psi(\vec{r}') \rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'}e^{i(\vec{k}'\cdot\vec{r}'-\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})}\langle a^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}a_{\vec{k}'}\rangle\\
&=\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\vec{k}}e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}'-\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})}\langle a^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}a_{\vec{k}}\rangle
\end{align}

where $\rho_1(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$ is the one particle density matrix, $\psi^{\dagger}(\vec{r}),  \psi(\vec{r}')$ are field operator that create a particle at $r$ and field operator that annihilates a particle at $r'$.

How does the summation on $\vec{k}'$ disappear in the last line? I have read the following paragraph but I didn't see any related explanation.

Comment: I do not have this text, but I would imagine it is something along the lines of $\langle a^\dagger_k,\,a_{k'}\rangle\sim\delta(k-k')$ which would be non-zero for $k=k'$ and thus you can drop the sum over $k'$.

Comment: This holds, IIRC, if the total momentum commutes with the Hamiltonian: $[H,P]=0$ and one computes the expectation value of the field operators in a common eigenstate.

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258289/computing-the-density-operator-commutation-relations-atland-simons) should help. It is one way to prove what I've mentioned above.